# php query inside a <script>

Tags: javascript, php, alert

I have a project that i need a confirmation from the user first before the program executes fully.

Here's the scenario:
The user will pick a date from a datepicker and then the program will automatically fetch/ detect if that date already existing in the database.

And if it's existing then it will prompt the user if he/she wants to overwrite it, and if it's true then the query will run.

Here’s my code so far but it's not properly working:

```
$filter = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_productivity WHERE scheduleDate='2013-12-15'") or die(mysql_error());
 if(mysql_num_rows($filter)==0)
 {
         $query = mysql_query("SELECT sched.campaign, sched.cmsName, sched.team,   sched.scheduleDate, sched.scheduleInput,sched.scheduleInput,STR_TO_DATE(MID(sched.scheduleInput, 7, 7), '%h:%i %p') as sIn, STR_TO_DATE(MID(sched.scheduleInput, 1, 8), '%h:%i %p') as sIn2,STR_TO_DATE(MID(sched.scheduleInput, 9, 12), '%h:%i %p') as sIn3, cms.loginDate, MAX(cms.logoutDate) as logoutDates, team.auxDate, team.general,team.outbound, team.authorized, team.break, team.lunch, team.email, team.coaching, team.systemDown, team.miscellaneous, team.training, team.general + team.outbound + team.authorized + team.break + team.lunch + team.email + team.coaching + team.systemDown + team.miscellaneous + team.training as totalAux FROM tbl_employeeschedules sched  LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_cmsloginout cms ON sched.cmsName = cms.agentName AND sched.scheduleDate = cms.loginDate LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_auxupload team ON sched.cmsName=team.cmsName AND sched.scheduleDate=team.auxDate WHERE sched.scheduleDate='2013-12-15' GROUP BY sched.cmsName ORDER BY sched.team") or die(mysql_error()); 
 }
 else
 {
   echo "<script> 
        var ans = confirm('Data dated 2013-12-15 already existing, Do you want to overwrite it?');
        if(ans==true)
        {
            $query = mysql_query('SELECT sched.campaign, sched.cmsName, sched.team, sched.scheduleDate, sched.scheduleInput,sched.scheduleInput,STR_TO_DATE(MID(sched.scheduleInput, 7, 7), '%h:%i %p') as sIn, STR_TO_DATE(MID(sched.scheduleInput, 1, 8), '%h:%i %p') as sIn2,STR_TO_DATE(MID(sched.scheduleInput, 9, 12), '%h:%i %p') as sIn3, cms.loginDate, MAX(cms.logoutDate) as logoutDates, team.auxDate, team.general,team.outbound, team.authorized, team.break, team.lunch, team.email, team.coaching, team.systemDown, team.miscellaneous, team.training, team.general + team.outbound + team.authorized + team.break + team.lunch + team.email + team.coaching + team.systemDown + team.miscellaneous + team.training as totalAux FROM tbl_employeeschedules sched  LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_cmsloginout cms ON sched.cmsName = cms.agentName AND sched.scheduleDate = cms.loginDate LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_auxupload team ON sched.cmsName=team.cmsName AND sched.scheduleDate=team.auxDate WHERE sched.scheduleDate='2013-12-15' GROUP BY sched.cmsName ORDER BY sched.team') or die(mysql_error());    

        }
    </script>";
```

}

There's no alert happening when I did this code.

Comment: You cannot make a PHP query from inside `script` tags. But you can use AJAX to make those calls to a seperate PHP script, and return the query.

Comment: You need to use AJAX. PHP runs on the server when creating the page, not when the page is being rendered by the browser.

Comment: This is because PHP is a server-side language - while you can definitely run JS within a PHP code, you cannot do otherwise, because JS is a client-side language. Please consider using AJAX instead.

Comment: Thanks guys, i should have need to use ajax instead. :))

Comment: @RyanWillis: Just to clarify, one *can* [call PHP inside `<script>`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php), specifically `<script language="php"></script>` is parsed the same as eg `<?php ?>`, it's just obviously not done in the browser as @Aljie tried.

Answer (score 0):

You have PHP code inside a JavaScript tag.  This will not work because the PHP code has to execute on the web server.  The `<script>` executes on the user's browser, long after the web server has processed the PHP code.

You need to do a post back to the web server with the results of the JavaScript `confirm` dialog box to do your next `SELECT` query on the server, not try to process it in the JS block